# VBA code for testing efficency

Tags: vba, excel, benchmarking

I am currently trying out code for timing efficiency (how fast it runs, basically).

The general consensus is that code with `ActiveCell`,`.Select`,`Selection` and so forth are basicly rejected for being slow and buggy, whereas code that uses variables and not `ActiveCell`,`.Select`,`Selection` are considered quicker and less buggy

The two codes I have made do the same thing, which is to enter a number 40000+1 every consecutive cell (so Cell A1 is 40000 then A2 is 40001 and so forth) and then converts those numbers into dates. One does this with `ActiveCell`, `Selection` and `Select`, while the other does it with varibles,`Long` and `Range`. I also did both with and then without `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to see how that worked as well.

The code `ActiveCell` etc. ran at `13494`,`26567`,`26489`,`14040`,`26598`(without `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) and `1154`,`1123`,`1123`,`1107`,`1170` (with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) "Milliseconds"

The code without `ActiveCell` ran at `905`,`905`,`905`,`671`,`687` (without `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) and ran at `577`,`609`,`577`,`577`,`562` (with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) "Milliseconds"

The milliseconds is in "Milliseconds" as the `Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long` I have been lead to believe isnt very accurate, I use it because the accurate ones are addins for excel and I unable to download or install anything on this PC, but gvies a decent idea of the speed the code runs at

The code that the efficency tests is the `For i = 1 To 1000` loop

Code with `ActiveCell`s:

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Sub UsingVaribles()

Dim NumberToday As Long
Dim StartTimer As Long
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

[A1].Select

NumberToday = 40000



StartTimer = GetTickCount

k = 1

    For q = 1 To 26

        For i = 1 To 1000
        NumberToday = NumberToday + 1
        Set rngCells = Cells(i, k)
        rngCells.Value = NumberToday
        Next i

    Range(rngCells, Cells(1, k)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" ' 1 bug out

    k = k + 1

    Next q

MsgBox (GetTickCount - StartTimer & " Milliseconds")


End Sub
```

Code without `ActiveCell`s:

```
Sub UsingActivecell()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

[A1].Select

NumberToday = 40000

Dim StartTimer As Long

StartTimer = GetTickCount

    For q = 1 To 26

        For i = 1 To 1000
        NumberToday = NumberToday + 1
        ActiveCell.Value = NumberToday
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next i

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select ' 3 issues with bug out, due to my incompitence
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select

Next q

MsgBox (GetTickCount - StartTimer & " Milliseconds")


End Sub
```

Comment: The same advice applies here as for time, encryption and other complicated, fundamental operations: Don't roll your own. There's some very god, very robust benchmarking code out there for VBA, if your focus is on effective benchmarking, I recommend you go seek it out.

Comment: @Zak As focus is sort of effective benchmarking as I am wanting to see which code runs quicker, `ActiveCell` or not `ActiveCell` VBA based code, as much as I have looked around I havent been able to find any concrete evidense that shows `ActiveCell` does or doesnt run quicker(other than a large quantity of people saying so)

Comment: You want to slow your code down? It might be better to put together something real and then change the way you reference, but my bet is the variation is negligible.

Comment: It's Excel, so why not attach or link to a chart of the computed times? Also, the speed increase mentioned by @Raystafarian is due to un-declared variables being created as Variant types. So your using extra memory AND it's slowing the code down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this isn't what you're asking, but what's up with your variables? You should always turn on `Option Explicit` which will catch things like `k`, `q` and `i` not being dimensioned.

When you don't define your variable, VBA defines it as a variant. I'm *pretty sure* variants are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

> Performance. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible
>   enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke
>   a method or property on such a variable, you always **incur late binding**
>   (at run time). **To force early binding (at compile time) and better
>   performance**, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast
>   it to the specific data type.

So you pay a penalty when you don't dimension your variables.

I imagine defining your variables might shave some milliseconds off *over the long run*.

---

For *variables* I'm getting **570**ish

For *selection* I'm getting **950**ish

For `i=1 to 10000`

- using your variables is giving me about **5200**
- while using option explicit I'm getting around **5100**.

For `i=1 to 50000`

- option explicit is **24165**
- your variables is **24476**

`Option Explicit` has the gainz.

And now, my version (why are you `[A1].Select`ing?) for `i=1 to 50000` comes in at **23182**. That right there should show you the `.select` statement was slowing it down.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Sub UsingVaribles()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim NumberToday As Long
    NumberToday = 40000
    Dim StartTimer As Long
    StartTimer = GetTickCount
    Dim rngCells As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    Dim i As Long
    Dim q As Long

    For q = 1 To 26
        For i = 1 To 50000
            NumberToday = NumberToday + 1
            Set rngCells = Cells(i, k)
            rngCells = NumberToday
        Next i
        Range(rngCells, Cells(1, k)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" ' 1 bug out
        k = k + 1
    Next q

    MsgBox (GetTickCount - StartTimer & " Milliseconds")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: For the `k`,`q` and `i` I never relised that it would reduce my code speed, now that I do I will be `Dim`ing them, the `[A1].Select` was most likely copyied from the `UsingActiveCell` sub (it was to save time rewriting everything)

Comment: I added some information about declaring variables to the answer.

Comment: Nice update on the answer, I've set this as the answer mainly due to the good information and varied testing on the code ... To anyone lese reading down this far, don't be afraid to post your own answers still, anything you can help to improve this code and anyone elses is good information!

Comment: Of course now I'll probably plot the results in R. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the `VBA.timer` function (a double with milliseconds) rather than `gettickcount`.